# Getting quantity between a range of months from 2 date parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that stores budget quantities for a company whose fiscal year begins 1st April and ends on 31st March the next year.

I have this query to extract figures for a particular month.

```
SELECT SUM(T1.U_Quantity) AS 'YTDBOwnMadeTea'
      FROM [SL_NTEL_DB_LIVE].[dbo].[@U_BUDG_MADETEA] T0
INNER JOIN [SL_NTEL_DB_LIVE].[dbo].[@U_BUDG_MADETEA_ROW] T1 
      ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE T1.U_Month = DATENAME(MONTH, '2015-04-01') AND T0.U_Source = 'NTEL'
```

There is an existing report that takes two parameters, a Start and End Date. (type datetime)

Table below: The month column is of type nvarchar.

[image]

How do I modify the query such when a user enters StartDate and EndDate e.g. 
1st May 2015 and 31st July 2015, I will get a quantity result of `12640`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show table structure of your 2 tables in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use couple of ways to do this.

One way would be to use [PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). Like this.

```
SELECT SUM(T1.U_Quantity) AS 'YTDBOwnMadeTea'
      FROM [SL_NTEL_DB_LIVE].[dbo].[@U_BUDG_MADETEA] T0
INNER JOIN [SL_NTEL_DB_LIVE].[dbo].[@U_BUDG_MADETEA_ROW] T1 
      ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE PARSE((T1.U_Month + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))) as datetime) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND T0.U_Source = 'NTEL'
```

Another way would be to use a numbers table to map your month name to a month number and use it in your query.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 1 as rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
MonthMap AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY rn ASC) as monthnumber FROM CTE
)
SELECT monthnumber,DATENAME(MONTH,DATEFROMPARTS(2016,monthnumber,1)) FROM MonthMap;
```

and then join it with your month table like this.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 1 as rn UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
MonthMap AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY rn ASC) as monthnumber FROM CTE
)
SELECT SUM(T1.U_Quantity) AS 'YTDBOwnMadeTea'
      FROM [SL_NTEL_DB_LIVE].[dbo].[@U_BUDG_MADETEA] T0
INNER JOIN [SL_NTEL_DB_LIVE].[dbo].[@U_BUDG_MADETEA_ROW] T1 
      ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
INNER JOIN MonthMap M ON T1.U_Month = DATENAME(MONTH,DATEFROMPARTS(2016,monthnumber,1))
WHERE M.monthnumber BETWEEN DATEPART(MONTH,@StartDate) AND DATEPART(MONTH,@EndDate)
AND T0.U_Source = 'NTEL';
```

You should compare both the approaches for performance. `PARSE` is simpler to use but would be difficult to index properly.

***On a Separate note**, you should avoid storing dates or date parts as month names as these take up more storage(even more since you are using `NVARCHAR`), and are difficult to use efficiently.*